# Postgres: How to returns json type projected data

Tags: json, postgresql

It might be a noob question, but would like to know the capabilities of postgres json output.

For the table below:

```
id | seconds | datetime 
1  | 10      | 2020-08-21 08:42:58.26+08
2  | 20      | 2020-08-21 10:20:00.01+08
3  | 10      | 2020-08-22 08:00:00.10+08
```

Is this possible to output in json like so?

```
[{
  "date" : "2020-08-21",
  "seconds_1" : 10,
  "seconds_2" : 20,
},
{
  "date" : "2020-08-22",
  "seconds_1" : 10
}]
```

I can manipulate the table result thru php/javascript, but just wondering if this is possible in postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a multi step aggregation:

```
select jsonb_agg(item)
from (
  select jsonb_build_object('date', dt)|| jsonb_object_agg(concat('seconds_', rn), seconds) item
  from (
    select datetime::date as dt,
           row_number() over (partition by datetime::date) as rn, 
           seconds
    from the_table
  ) t
  group by dt  
) r
```

The inner most query is used to number the rows per date, this can't be done at the same level where the grouping by date is done, because then the numbers would be wrong (as window functions are evaluated *after* grouping)

The second level aggregates all "seconds" for each date and builds a JSON value from that. The last level then aggregates everything into a JSON array.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d5368eaa4271cad2a71bb016c68da3d)

---

If you don't care about the numbers that make the "seconds" key unique, you can use the `id` column and simplify the query a bit:

```sql
select jsonb_agg(item)
from (
  select jsonb_build_object('date', datetime::date)|| jsonb_object_agg(concat('seconds_', id), seconds) item
  from the_table
  group by datetime::date
) r
```

Comment: Just a followup question for performance, which approach is better compared to just manipulating the data in a specific language?